# How decompress zip with a password in windows 8

Tags: c#, windows-8, zip

I have a zip password file and know this password. I need open this zip file in a Windows 8 metro app program code. But `System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive` is not supported zip with  password in Windows 8 metro app program code.

Is there another way?

thanks

Comment: You should indicate what programming language you are working with in the question's tags.

Comment: have you tried to winRAR and you must know the password. If you dont know password some other softwares are there to hack.

Comment: By Windows 8 program do you mean a Windows Store App (or whatever it's called these days)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [SharpZipLib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SharpZipLib)

```
SharpZipLibZip.Zip.FastZip zip = new ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.FastZip();
zip.Password = "password";
zip.CreateZip(zipfilename, "temp\\", true, null, null);
```

Comment: SharpZipLib is not support net 4.5 too.  I need decompress zip with password in windows metro app program.  please help me thanks

Answer (score 1):

I use  [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/).

Unzipping with passwords can be done like this (from the c# examples page):

```
using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(ExistingZipFile))
{
    ZipEntry e = zip["TaxInformation-2008.xls"];
    e.ExtractWithPassword(BaseDirectory, Password);
}
```

Comment: DotNetZip is not support net 4.5.  I need decompress zip with password in windows metro app program.  please help me thanks